# How to install a clean Windows 11 on Laptop that has Windows 10 Pro OEM

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, oem, windows-11-upgrade

My laptop came with Windows 10 Pro OEM

Works fine.

I got a notification from Microsoft of an upgrade to Windows 11

I did the upgrade and I have Windows 11

I want to format my laptop.

Is there a way to clean install Windows 11 without using Windows 10 image that I have?

Comment: Yes; The simplest method is use Reset from within Windows and choose the option to keep nothing. You will end up in the exact, and I do mean exactly the same state, as if you used a Windows 11 installer.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

- the Installation Assistant (do **not** use this, it is for upgrading win10 to win11)
- Windows 11 Installation Media Creation Tool
- Windows 11 Disk Image (ISO)

Both these options allow you to do a clean install.

https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11

You can also use the Reset this PC functionality.

- Open Settings on Windows 11.
- Click on System.
- Click on Recovery on the right side.
- Under the “Recovery options” section, in the “Reset this PC” setting, click the Reset PC button.
- Click the "Remove everything" option to perform a fresh install of Windows 11.

Make sure you have backups!

I would recommend the Reset this PC option, because it is easier.